# How do I calculate quotient and remainder?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that prompts a user to input how many donuts they are going to eat, and then prints out how many dozen and single donuts it is.

For example, if the user types in `29`, the program would say:

> This is 2 dozen plus 5 single donuts.*".

I have been able to figure out how to print dozens, but I cannot figure out how to get it to print singles.

I am also having some trouble with the if-statements. If the user types in `29` , I expect the program to output:

> Mmmmmmm......donuts!

Instead, it is printing out:

> What's for dessert...cinnamon rolls?

How can I fix this?

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int donuts;
  std:cout << "Enter how many donuts you want to eat: " << endl;
  cin >> donuts;
  int dozens = donuts / 12;
  //int singles = donuts % 6;
  cout << "This is " << dozens << " dozen plus " << singles << " single donuts" << endl;


  if (donuts == 0)
    cout << "On a diet or something?" << endl;
  else if (donuts == 1 || donuts == 2)
    cout << "You don't seem very hungry today." << endl;
  else if (donuts >= 3 && donuts <= 6)
    cout << "Just an appetizer for you?" << endl;
  else if (donuts >= 7 || donuts <= 9)
    cout << "What's for dessert...cinnamon rolls?" << endl;
  else if (donuts >= 10 || donuts <= 12)
    cout << "You're a donut freak!" << endl;
  else if (donuts > 12)
    cout << "Mmmmmmm......donuts!" << endl;
}
```

I tried:

- using modulo with different numbers.
- changing my if-statements to else-if-statements.

Comment: Since you know how many full dozens are in donuts, why not do `int singles = donuts - (dozens * 12)`?

Comment: *I tried to use modulo with different numbers* -- This does not require usage of modulo at all, just a simple grade school subtraction.

Comment: Either do as @BRemmelzwaal suggests or use modulo 12.

Comment: Minor point: you don't have to check `donuts >= 3`; you already know that, because you wouldn't have gotten past the preceding `if`s if it wasn't. Well, not quite; the code should first check for `donuts < 0` and say that there's something wrong. Once you've done that, you don't have to check `donuts >= 7` or `donuts >= 10` or `donuts > 12`.

Answer (score 2):

Singles can be calculated by using modulo 12 and it doesn't display what you want when you enter 29 because the two else if statements near the end use `||` which is 'or' when you need to use `&&` which is 'and'. Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int donuts;
  std:cout << "Enter how many donuts you want to eat: " << endl;
  cin >> donuts;
  int dozens = donuts / 12;
  int singles = donuts % 12;
  cout << "This is " << dozens << " dozen plus " << singles << " single donuts" << endl;


  if (donuts == 0)
    cout << "On a diet or something?" << endl;
  else if (donuts == 1 || donuts == 2)
    cout << "You don't seem very hungry today." << endl;
  else if (donuts >= 3 && donuts <= 6)
    cout << "Just an appetizer for you?" << endl;
  else if (donuts >= 7 && donuts <= 9)
    cout << "What's for dessert...cinnamon rolls?" << endl;
  else if (donuts >= 10 && donuts <= 12)
    cout << "You're a donut freak!" << endl;
  else if (donuts > 12)
    cout << "Mmmmmmm......donuts!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Even better: don't do redundant tests; then you don't need to worry about `||` vs. `&&`. Just check for `donuts < 0` initially; then you can remove `donuts >= 3`, `donuts >= 7`, `donuts >= 10`, and `donuts > 12`. +1.

Comment: True, although it is easier to see what output corresponds to what range of numbers.